# Android click going to wrong activity

Tags: android, onclick

I have an activity that has multiple clickable views. When you click on one of them - new instance of the same activity class is called with new arguments.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SameActivity.class);
// put extras
startActivity(i);
```

This is done in onClick method. The problem is that when you double click any view really fast, you can see that new Activity is opened and then it acts like I clicked on one of the views again (in the newly created activity). And then it renavigates again.

log looks like:

```
onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
onClick()
onPause()
onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
onClick()
onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
onStop()
onStop()
```

Why and how to avoid it?

**EDIT:**
Tried using setEnabled(false) but that had no effect.

What's more my further tests showed that onClick is actually triggered by the newly created view. Could it be device's fault? Too slow response or so?

Comment: Are you using the onClick attribute of your button in your XML layout? Maybe try using `setOnClickListener` instead?

Comment: I actually am setting listeners in onCreate.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I really hope you have a good reason for doing this... because starting the same `Activity` on top of another sounds kind of pointless in my opinion.

Second of all, perhaps you can try calling `myButton.setEnabled(false)` in `onPause` and `myButton.setEnabled(true)` in `onResume`, while making sure that the button is disabled to start in the XML.

Comment: why not just setEnabled(fasle) in `onClick`..?

Comment: Yeah, that'd probably be more readable. :) The difference would be only a few milliseconds though, most likely.

Comment: I restart activity (with no history set to true) so that I can make it a bit simpler, to make it a set-up-and-forget type of thing. I will soon try playing around with setEnable.